# Can you find the standard deviation of the residuals of a linear regression using R-squared?

Tags: regression, self-study, standard-deviation, residuals

Ridham Kamath, CFA, is an equity analyst with Morgan Yelnats India Ltd. The firm has more than $10 billion of assets under management. Kamath also contributes quantitative analysis for asset valuation. Kamath collects monthly returns for the last 5 years for OXIN Leisure and S&P CNX Index. The results of the regression are as follows:

[image]
[image]

**Question**What is the standard deviation of the residuals?

**My Attempt**: R-squared = $\frac{\text{RSS}}{\text{TSS}} = \frac{\text{Explained Variation}}{\text{Total Variation}}$.

Therefore $0.6527 = \frac{152.35}{152.35 + \text{Sum of the Squared Residuals}}$  implies that the Sum of Squared Residuals is 81.065.  Now to find the standard deviation of this, I just divide by the degrees of freedom for the residuals, 58, and then take the square root of that.  So I get that the standard deviation of the residuals is about 1.18.

Is this method correct?